# litres and percentage question. Solve through equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

A lab technician needs 5 L of a solution containing 8 % salt. Unfortunately, her supply solutions are 4 % salt and 11% salt. How many litres of each supply solution must she combine to get the 5 L of 8 % solution?

Help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance. I mainly just need help starting the question!

Comment: I spent time to edit and answer helpneeded's another post just now. After getting my answer, he just deleted the post. No upvote, no accept!!

Comment: I realized I was doing the wrong question and it wasn't assigned in my homework. I finished it anyways, and got the answer. I figured I didn't need to leave it up, because there wasn't much explanation. Clearly you don't care too much about mathematics if you are encouraging others not to help me figure out a question, i truly do need help with. Please do not post on my answers anymore if you are going to be disrespectful and unhelpful. Have a nice day, and quit being so sensitive. Not my fault you require recognition, and an "upvote" to feel intelligent.

Comment: Wow,,, we have a math-lover here!! To be honest, I don't think a math-lover will just want to find somebody to get his homework done, without even trying a little bit effort....

Comment: Firstly, I am a young women. So please stop using masculine pronouns. As for effort, I have attempted many questions and was having trouble with the ones I have asked online. You have no idea how much work I have done. Quit arguing with me, go answer some more questions and then get mad when someone else hurts your ego. Let it go, theres bigger issues in the world then a young women having difficulty answering a grade 10 math question and asking for help, only to delete the question and not upvote or accept the poorly done answer.  Seriously, get a life.

Comment: OK! You need not upvote, you need not accept, You don't even need to say thank you, as you didn't. But at least you should leave the question there for others with similar problems to learn. But not just deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need $5$ liters and an $8\%$ solution, so we need $0.4$ liters of solute.

We then have $A+B=5$ and $0.04A+0.11B=0.4$.

Dividing the first equation by $25$ gives $0.04A+0.04B=0.2$.

Subtracting, we get $0.07B=0.2$, so $B=\displaystyle \frac{20}{7}$.

Using that $A+B=5$, we have that $A = \displaystyle \frac{15}{7}$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle \frac{15}{7}$L of $4\%$ salt solution and $\displaystyle \frac{20}{7}$L of $11\%$ salt solution must be mixed to form $5$L of $8\%$ solution.

Comment: for these problems, use a system of equations. one for the amount of solute, and one for the amount of liquid

Comment: At least now you've learned how to say "thank you"!!